# Calling setLayoutParams() in onLayout method of custom view group does nothing

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, custom-view

I'm extending RelativeLayout and want to set position of my childViews in onLayout method. So here is the code:

```
 override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, l: Int, t: Int, r: Int, b: Int) {

    val margin = Math.round(beautyButton!!.measuredWidth * 1.75).toInt()

    beautyButton!!.visibility = View.GONE

    var params = defaultSeekbar!!.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
    params.setMargins(margin,0,margin,0)
    params.addRule(CENTER_IN_PARENT)
    params.removeRule(ALIGN_PARENT_START)
    params.removeRule(START_OF)

    var params2 = beautySeekbar!!.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
    params2.setMargins(margin,0,margin,0)
    params2.addRule(CENTER_IN_PARENT)
    params2.removeRule(ALIGN_PARENT_START)
    params2.removeRule(START_OF)

   super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b)
}
```

I want to set position of seekbars depending on size of Button.
And this does nothing. I also tried something like this, but result is the same.

```
defaultSeekbar!!.layout(margin,defaultSeekbar!!.measuredWidth,margin,defaultSeekbar!!.measuredHeight)
```

Can someone help me please to figure out how can I set position of my child views before drawing them to screen?

***Thanks everyone for the answers in advance!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a bit of code. You can't just retrieve a View's LayoutParams and then modify them, as the framework needs some way to know they've been updated.

Add these lines:

```
defaultSeekbar!!.layoutParams = params
beautySeekbar!!.layoutParams = params2
```

Remember, Kotlin likes to convert Java setter/getter methods to what it calls the Property Access Syntax, where they look like variables. The catch is that `View#setLayoutParams()` doesn't just change a variable in View. It also calls some other stuff so the framework knows that that View has been changed.

Another thing. I'm guessing you're doing the `!!` because you're not initializing the SeekBars immediately. You can use the lazy init syntax, if it works for your situation (I can't tell because you haven't posted that code):

```
defaultSeekbar by lazy { findViewById<WhateverClass>(R.id.whatever) }
beautySeekbar by lazy { findViewById<WhateverClass>(R.id.whatever2) }
```

They'll only be initialized once they're called, and then that instance will remain.